# Запрос на обновление данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть две таблицы: рейтинг и оценки. Мне нужно после изменения данных в таблице оценки поле оценка, обновить поле рейтинг в таблице рейтинг. То есть у кого самый высокий балл в того рейтинг 1, и так далее.
Как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего сделать это с помощью триггеров событий `ON UPDATE` и `ON INSERT`(если предполагается добавление данных) таблицы с оценками.